# Comparing dates coming from different files in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to link two Excel files and compare the values from first one in the second one, but I have a problem at some point.

[image]

So the date *28/07/2021* comes from the other file (which is call 3WLA). I had to use the function `TEXT(..., "dd/mm/yyyy")` otherwise it displays *44405* which is an other form of the date. Now I want to compare this date with other ones but it doesn't work as showed in the pictures below.

[image]

The picture shows the comparison of two dates coming from the other excel file 3WLA (still using the function `TEXT(..., "dd/mm/yyyy")`). We clearly see that there is a problem as it should display TRUE. In the same way, when I compare a date from 3WLA (i.e. using `TEXT(..., "dd/mm/yyyy")`) with a date random in my file it give me the following

[image]

where *28/07/2021* is given by  `= TEXT('[3WLA.xlsx]Block-First-Fix'!$AM$1,"dd/mm/yyyy")` and *29/07/2021* by `= 29/07/2021`

Comment: You are comapring _strings_, not dates.  Just because those strings look like dates, doesn't make them actual dates.  Rather than converting your dates to strings with `TEXT(...`, store tham as actual dates, amd formt the cells to display them as you wish.  Them formula such as `C1<C2` will work

Answer (score 0):

chris neilsen already gave you the answer in the comments.
To clarify further: The text "29/07/2021" and the date formatted to look like "29/07/2021" are different data types. To help with this MS Excel automatically formats numbers and dates to be aligned to the right and normal text to be aligned to the left
[image]

In B1 you can see that the date has been formatted in the same way as per the formula in A2, but since the output in B2 is of the text data type, the two are not considered the same.

You can use the formula `DATEVALUE` to convert from text to date serial number. (Read more about date serial numbers [here](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-date-and-time)).

If your texts with dates are too different from your local settings date formats, `DATEVALUE` might not give you correct results. In that case use DATE function in combination with some text functions such as `LEFT`, `MID`, `RIGHT`

[image]

You can format the cell to make the date more readable using either the number formatting field or the dropdown from the ribbon

[image] [image]